# Using a combination of SESSION Vars and COOKIE Vars in PHP

Tags: php, session, variables, cookies

Heyo,

Odd question... is it possible/ ok. To use a combination of SESSION variables and COOKIE variables... in PHP?

I know SESSIONS are stored server side and COOKIES client side...

Is there any chance of interference? What is the best practise?

Christopher

Comment: Best practice for what use? Here is an article about sessions and cookies: http://shiflett.org/articles/the-truth-about-sessions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, sessions are a combination between sessions and cookies since the session ID is stored in a cookie client side. You are free to do pretty much what ever you want with both as long as you remember:

- Cookies are stored on the client computer. A savvy user has absolutely full control of the contents of a cookie, so don't make assumptions about it's content
- Session variables are stored in memory on your server, so keep in mind the amount of data you hold for each visitor

[PHP's documentation on sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.session.php)

Comment: thanks I presumed that this was the case... so as long as the variables of the cookie are of consequence to security I should be fine.

Comment: Note also that sessions are stored in files on the server, not necessarily in memory unless you use something like memcached to store session data.

Answer (score 1):

You can mix them.  By default, the session cookie is set to PHPSESSID that contains the unique session identifier used to associate the client to the session data on the server.  As long as you don't interfere with this cookie, it is okay.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of interference it is like just any other two arrays in PHP.
There are some specific issues with each you need to know, like at what phase you can assign variables to each of them etc.